# RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'

Tags: python, linux, terminal, devops

I am a beginner in devops field and I learnt different technologies now I am moving to project side by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvL_FGs--a0&t=459s) video and when I **run virtualenv -p python3.7 env** it shows **RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'**

expected: to generate an env file
I reinstalled Python and tried different versions of Python; it works in other versions but not in this one.
PS: I am on ubuntu 20.04 system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with 3.11. I first tried to give the full path to virtualenv:
`virtualenv venv --python=/usr/bin/python3.11`

This gave me a different error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command'\n'**

Which I was able to fix by installing python3.11-distutils (which would be python3.7-distutils in your case)

`sudo apt-get install python3.11-distutils`